# How can I get the flowers to open while growing

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a setup where I can control the growth of multiple flowers by scaling and moving an empty. So far so good but I can't find a way to get the flowers to open while growing.

[image: Current setup in action]

With the setup shown on the picture below, I'm able to control the rotation of every blossoms on every flowers. But I couldn't find the proper setup to tell geometry node to only rotate blossoms when the stem (spline) is growing.

[image: My Geometry Node setup]

If I understood correctly I need to find a way to use the index of each spline (stems) but I'm completely lost at this point.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about geometry nodes yet, but have you checked out this tutorial from Bad Normals? https://youtu.be/uslTaqiv_7k

Comment: @Copperplate Yep, watched it and it was really helpful when I wanted to add leaves to the stems. Unfortunately it doesn't help for my current problem :) Right now Blossoms are instanced on each point of a curve circle which is positioned on the last vertex of each splines and not along the splines like on the tutorial.
I also watched this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVK7n9rMsHI from BlenderDude and this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSkaM-8Vgz8&t from Entagma.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. You're clearly ahead of me on this one. Hope you find a good solution. If you do, be sure to post the answer back here to help others. :-)

Comment: I sure will do ! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those very individual questions that require a very individual answer.... In your case you would have to structure a few things differently.

You first create the pistil and the petals as one object. Then you instantiate this object at the endpoints of the stems.

After instantiation, however, you no longer have any influence on the transformation of the individual objects that make up your flower.

However, if you instantiate the pistil first, and then the circles at which your petals are to be instantiated, you will have full control over the rotation of the individual petals in the following step.

It might look something like this:

[image]

Also, I check here additionally if the value for the scaling is above $0$ at all. If not, then no petals should be instantiated at all at this point. This reduces the created geometry considerably.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are fantastic ! Exactly what I needed and the "Querry points" is the icing on the cake. I'm going to use it very often :)
During my experiments I came to the same conclusion but I encountered other issues when scaling blossoms. I was trying to distribute them around the last vertex of the spline and as a result their origin was at their center and not on the spline's last vertex.
Anyway ! Thank you again for your time, I'll post the final result when ready !

Comment: I have a follow up question ! I would like to randomize the scale of each flowers (Pistil + Blossoms) and possibly the scale of each blossoms independently. My first thought was to multiply a random value node with the scale value coming from the empty. But it seems the scale changes randomly when the spline get smaller. How should I do to avoid that ?
Captures for reference :
https://imgur.com/nfr61Ps
https://imgur.com/u9hvBtT

Comment: @Ben For that, you could use this setup: https://blend-exchange.com/b/bxVzSQby/ Here I just hooked in another random node (and applied the scaling to the petals as well, which I honestly forgot to do in the previous example).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This method was pretty simple I should have thought of it. Although the problem still persist with random rotations or random materials as shown in this example : https://imgur.com/xbsQJCL (node setup : https://imgur.com/ab6jBsm)
I'm very embarrassed to bother you again. If you could point me out in the right direction that you would be even more awesome !
If I understood correctly, it happens because the last index of the spline keeps changing when the latter is being trimmed ?

Comment: @Ben Here is another suggestion (which should also solve all your concerns): https://blend-exchange.com/b/3Ql487Mj/ I also took the liberty of adding some interesting learning examples. Have fun with it!

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to do something like that ! Excellent ! Thanks again for your time and your generous help :) I couldn't finish my project before this week end but I'll will definitely show you the result when I get back.

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful advices :)
This is the result so far https://imgur.com/1suz4jd
There are few details I'm not happy with but I like where this is going.

Comment: @Ben Hey I like that! Well done so far! Would you share your finished blend file here for others, or is that too much disclosure for you?

Comment: Sure ! I have a few things I'd like to do before sharing it. Also I'm using https://lightningboystudio.gumroad.com/ for the shaders. To make the blend file usable for anyone I need to modify them first.

Comment: @Ben Wonderful, I think that's great! It always pleases me to see what others make in the end from the answers that are given here (At least a picture would be nice). Am already very excited.