# Geometry nodes affect instances with instancer data before getting instanced

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

So I'm making a flower field grow controlled by an empty with geometry nodes and I would like the flowers to open their petals during the grow animation at the edge of the empty. This would require Blender to change the rotation parameter of the petal instances before the entire flower gets instanced on points on the ground. Is this somehow possible? As the instancer of the petals doesn't know that there will be multiple flowers it seems like quite a hard task, I'm open to rearranging the nodes tho.

So I want to get the empty interaction data from here
[image: So I want to get the empty interaction data from here]

Back to here and make the petals open while scaling them up
[image: Back to here and make the petals open while scaling them up]

Blend file: [image]

I hope you can help me, stay safe and have a great day ^^

Comment: Here are a few answers that might help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271797/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275954/

Comment: To achieve the goal, you would have to restructure some things here. You can only rotate the petals afterwards if you have access to these instances. Why this is so is explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestions ^^
It's now nearly impossible to still implement it tho, as I'm now using multiple different flowers and instance the collection.